# iOS Documents/Inbox folder new coming data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm writing an ios app and I managed to add it to "open with.." feature for any other types.My question is after I opened the file with my app how can handle it? I know it will be saved in `Documents/Inbox` folder in the app however my app will be dynamic and will extend in time.I need to access initially opened file's variables (like name, path etc).

My second question is, after I get the file I want to show `ViewController1` rather than when the app normally started `ViewController`. Should I need to store the count of `Documents/Inbox` files or are there any other ways?

Comment: are there any unclear points?

Comment: I solved it.. For any one who interested ,it can be handled in AppDelegate .